# This error comes up "Conversion from string "found" to type 'Long' is not valid."

Tags: vb.net

Im making a anti-virus in VB 10 but this error comes up"Conversion from string "delete" to type 'Long' is not valid."
I dont understand how to add more then one word like "virus" and "delete" heres my code:

```
If TextBox1.Text.Contains("virus" Or "delete") Then MsgBox("Malicilouse file detected ",
        MsgBoxStyle.Critical) Else 
    MsgBox("The file(s) are safe")
```

Could someone please help me!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
If TextBox1.Text.Contains("virus") Or TextBox1.Text.Contains("delete") Then MsgBox("Malicilouse file detected ",
    MsgBoxStyle.Critical) Else 
MsgBox("The file(s) are safe")
```